# Scraping tag attribute BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would scrape all `data-oid` tag from this page, but return nothing in the output

Code

```
url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/south-korea/k-league-2/bucheon-fc-1995-jeonnam/EDwej14E/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_='table-main')

for rows in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    for row in rows.find_all('td'):
        data = row.get_attrs['data-oid']
        print(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part table part of the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To get the data along with the tags with `data-oid=` parameters, you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/south-korea/k-league-2/bucheon-fc-1995-jeonnam/EDwej14E/"
match_id = "EDwej14E"  # <-- this is the last part of URL

api_url = "https://www.betexplorer.com/match-odds/{}/1/1x2/".format(match_id)

headers = {"Referer": "https://www.betexplorer.com"}
data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data["odds"], "html.parser")

# your code:
table = soup.find("table", class_="table-main")
for rows in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    for row in rows.select("td[data-oid]"):
        data = row["data-oid"]
        print(data)
```

Prints:

```
...

4kqjpxv464x0xc6aif
4kqjpxv464x0xc6aie
4kqjpxv498x0x0
4kqjpxv464x0xc6aif
4kqjpxv464x0xc6aie
4kqjpxv498x0x0
4kqjpxv464x0xc6aif
```